# Which ip is the server ip to use on the host file on centos 7 and to register domain nameserver

Tags: linux, server, centos, hosting, ip-address

It's first time to create a server (Centos 7) to host my websites, And I tried out which ip address is used for the host file on centos 7 and to register domain nameserver. I have entered the ip addr in the command line but not sure which ip should be used. Here is the copy from the command line.

```
 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
 qlen 1
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP
 qlen 1000
     link/ether 08:00:27:af:b0:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
        valid_lft 85832sec preferred_lft 85832sec
     inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feaf:b021/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
 qlen 1000
     link/ether 52:54:00:87:c4:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state
 DOWN qlen 1000
     link/ether 52:54:00:87:c4:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get public IP for DNS (Domain Name Server) by using this command

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

Output of this command will give Public IP of your server.